# How can I make detox run certain tests before others, or control the test order?

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, e2e-testing, detox

I have two test files, and one of them relies on the activity of the other (i.e. A.e2e.ts needs to run before B.e2e.ts).

I considered that there might be two possible solutions to this: 1. Run the test suites in a specific order, or 2. Run the tests from one suite as a function before running the second suite.

I tried implementing a custom jest sequencer in line with the recommendations in [this article](https://dev.to/jonasmerlin/in-what-order-does-jest-execute-tests-anyway-and-how-to-change-it-26pm), but that did not work; B.e2e.ts still ran before A.e2e.ts.

I've also tried using the `--reuse` flag that detox provides, but as these tests are designed to run in CI and they advise against using it there, I am reluctant to utilise that.

So how can I make sure that A.e2e.ts runs, the instance of the app is not terminated or deleted, and then B.e2e.ts runs?

Comment: Facing similiar problem here. Found a solution?